# web.config transform not executing on publish

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment, web.config-transform

I use web.config transforms all the time and when I make a new site/project, I often copy a previous site, rename the *.csproj and rename oldsite to newsite inside the csproj as necessary.  I do this often, but for some reason one of my projects will not run its transforms on publish.  I don't even know what to show you in this post, so I'll update the question as necessary based on what you want to see.  Googling around I didn't find much.  But here is what I can tell you:

1) My web.config does **not** have a namespace on it, my web.release.pittsburgh.config has the 'transform' namespace on it.

2) I copied the contents of a working web.release.pittsburgh.config into the none working one and it still didn't work.

3) When I publish a working site, in the output, I see some 'web config transform' output after a line like 'Publish Pipeline Collect Files Phase', and I see a step 'Transformed Web.config using...' and finally a 'Publish Pipeline Transform Phase' output line.  In my none working project, I go from 'Publish Pipeline Collect Files Phase' directly to 'Publish Pipeline Transform Phase' with nothing in between.

I tried comparing the *.csproj files to look for anything obvious and I didn't see anything.

Let me know if you have any ideas or would like any specific information.

Comment: Not sure this will help or not. Just a try. Go to "Configuration Manager" in visual studio. Look for active solution configurations and click on "New" and add "release.pittsburgh" configuration.

Comment: I have that there already.  I've also deleted all web.config transforms, right clicked on web.config and said 'Add Transforms' and it adds web.Release.Pittsburgh.config.

Comment: @RajKarri So even though your suggestion wasn't the solution, it helped me find the solution.  Not sure if you should answer it or I should answer my own, but when I viewed Release.Pittsburgh in Configuration manager, for some reason the client site's configuration was 'Release' instead of 'Release.Pittsburgh'.  When I flipped that setting, things started to work.

Comment: Good to hear you are able to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure below things are configured properly.

1) "Release.Pittsburgh" configuration is available or not. If not click on configuration manager and add new configuration.

[image]

2) Once configuration is available in the list, click on "Configuration Manager" and make sure all project configurations are set appropriately for "Release.Pittsburgh". If not, set it.

3) This last step is just to make sure transformations are getting added properly or not (Right click on web.config).

[image]

Once all are good, go for publish website.